# How to Store all Children from a StackPanel in a List?

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf

I have 6 Labels and 6 Objects (1 Datepicker, 2 comboboxes and 3 textboxes).
The Labels names are columnnames from a mysql database. And the content of the objects are the values for this.

If I click "Save" i want to save the values into the database.

What I found (but doesn't work because I have not the same amount of textboxes like the labels):

```
string query = "INSERT INTO "+ privateCustomerTablename +" (";
                for (int i = 0; i < textboxes.Count; i++)
                {
                    var column = labels[i];
                    if (i < textboxes.Count - 1)
                        query += column.Name + ",";
                    else
                        query += column.Name;
                }
                query += ") VALUES (";
                for (int i = 0; i < textboxes.Count; i++)
                {
                    var value = textboxes[i];
                    if (i < textboxes.Count - 1)
                        query += "'" + value.Text + "',";
                    else
                        query += "'" + value.Text + "')";
                }
```

So I though to store all Children of a Stackpanel (I have 2 Stackpanels, 1 for Labels and 1 for the objects) to change textboxes.Count in the objectlist count.

But How I can store the Children of a Stackpanel with different objects in it in a list to do that?

Comment: You shouldn't be constructing a SQL query by just concatenating strings like this; you should be using a parameterized query.

Comment: I have bad experience with parameters. The Parameters doesnt work often.

Comment: The alternative is [much, much worse](https://xkcd.com/327/).  Take the time to learn how to use them properly.  It's simply a necessity, not just something nice to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But How I can store the Children of a Stackpanel with different objects in it in a list to do that?

You could store all children in a single `List<UIElement>`:

```
List<UIElement> allElements = stackPanel1.Children.OfType<UIElement>().ToList();
```

Or you could store elements of a specific in a specialized list, e.g.:

```
List<TextBox> allTextBoxesInTheStackPanel = stackPanel1.Children.OfType<TextBox>().ToList();
```

Does this answer your question?

As for the SQL part you should always prefer using parameters:

[Why do we always prefer using parameters in SQL statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/why-do-we-always-prefer-using-parameters-in-sql-statements)